# How do I get an image to fill a table cell's width in Outlook?

Tags: html, outlook

I'm trying to build the html for an email.  In my browser Outlook client (and Gmail client) it renders like this, which is **good**

[image: nicely rendered - image fills cell]

In my O365 Outlook desktop app, it renders like this, with an **unwanted margin** at the right, which is **bad**, and the wrong colours (which I think I can fix):

[image: badly rendered - image does not fill cell]

Here's my code (it's actually a template, hence the `{banner}`):

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="700px" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
            <div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #404040; color: white; width: 100%;">
                <table width="100%" style="border: 1px solid red; border-spacing: 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0;"><img src="{Banner}" style="margin-bottom: 0; width: 100%;"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0; width: 50%; background: ">should be left-aligned with image</td>
                        <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0; width: 50%; text-align: right;">should be right-aligned with image</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap your entire table in a 100% width and then a second table inside with the table width set to 800 like below, this will remove your whitespace on the right.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
       <td>
          <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
             <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td width="700" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                   <div style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0; margin: 0; background: #404040; color: white; width: 100%;">
                      <table width="100%" style="border: 1px solid red; border-spacing: 0;">
                         <tr>
                            <td colspan="4" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0;"><img src="..." style="margin-bottom: 0; width: 100%;"/></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0; width: 50%; background: ">should be left-aligned with image</td>
                            <td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 0; width: 50%; text-align: right;">should be right-aligned with image</td>
                         </tr>
                      </table>
                   </div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```